# @Html.ActionLink() Producing Unexpected Results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I'm stumped on what seems to be a very strange issue.

In my Razor markup, I have:

```
@Html.ActionLink("World", "Browse", "Destination")
```

But the HTML produced is:

```
<a href="/Destination/Browse/1/africa-middle-east">World</a>
```

Note that the additional data is, in fact, valid data that I'm using in other links. But why the heck does it show up here? I can even verify that the first line produces the second line by inspecting it in the debugger.

I know I'm doing something really stupid here. I just don't see what it is.

Comment: It comes from the existing route data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it is taking the old route values for building the a tag. check [this](http://www.iwantmymvc.com/2011-03-03-actionlink-adding-extra-parameters) article for a similar scenario.

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493066%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload and try to explicitly pass null as RouteValues and see what changes it brings

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues
)
```

So your code can be re-written as

```
@Html.ActionLink("World", "Browse", "Destination",null)
```

Alternatively you may try to use this version also

```
<a href="Url.Action("Browser", "Destination")">World</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, it is the route data. Looks like the dev that implemented this is using `@Html.ActionLink("World", "Browse", "Destination", new { id = "" }, null)` in other locations so I used that. Thanks.